# Horizontal ScrollView with content on two lines

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I would like to render an horizontal scroll view with two rows of items, where the items have dynamic sizes. I have already tried to set a height to the scroll view and apply to its containerStyle flex-wrap with flex direction column, as suggested here [React Native horizontal FlatList with multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939823/react-native-horizontal-flatlist-with-multiple-rows).

However, the result is not as expected since two elements in a column take the same size.

```
<View style={{height: 80}}>
  <ScrollView 
    horizontal={true} 
    containerStyle={{
      flexDirection: "column",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      alignItems: "flex-start"
    }}
  >
    {data.map(d => renderElement(d))}
  </ScrollView>
</View

renderElement = (d: string) => (
    <View 
      style={{
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#898989",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 12,
        margin: 3,
        height: 24
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 8, fontSize: 16, color:"#898989#"}}>
       {d}
      </Text>
    </View>
)
```

current result:
[image]

Comment: can you provide the sample data and renderElement() method implementation to. ?

Comment: I added the renderElement function, and edited a bit the initial code as I am using directly containerStyle from scrollView. Data here is an array of string

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

A similar way to wrap a list of elements with multiple columns and rows, as a horizontal carousel with a desired of rows, is by making use of the wrapping prop a nested Flatlist `columnWrapperStyle`, which only works with a vertical flatlist, given that the only thing we can define is the number of columns (sadly not the number of rows) you can define an additional function `getNumColumns()` (as shown down here):

```js
const getNumColumns = (listLength) => {
    //listLength/numRows = numColumns
    return listLength / 2; // change the '2' for the disired number of rows
  };
```

now to avoid errors apply the following props in the child flatlist in this manner:

```js
columnWrapperStyle={getNumColumns(list.length) > 1
                              ? { flexWrap: "wrap" }
                              : undefined
                          }
numColumns={getNumColumns(list.length)}
```

this is a possible version of the code for your example:

```js
<View style={{ height: 80 }}>
                        <ScrollView
                          horizontal={true}
                          containerStyle={{
                            flexDirection: "column",
                            flexWrap: "wrap",
                            alignItems: "flex-start",
                          }}
                        >
                          <FlatList
                            scrollEnabled={false} //this optional to avoid the vertical scroll
                            columnWrapperStyle={
                              getNumColumns(data.length) > 1
                                ? { flexWrap: "wrap" }
                                : undefined
                            }
                            numColumns={getNumColumns(data.length)}
                            data={data}
                            style={{ paddingTop: 10 }} //choose your own padding
                            renderItem={(d) =>renderElement(d)}
                          />
                        </ScrollView>
                      </View>
```